# PhpStorm List of Projects

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any opportunity to manage list of all projects in phpstorm? Maybe creating groups of projects...
I found only this: File -> Reopen -> (list) / Clear list.
Thanx

Answer (score 7):

Not yet, please [vote for the better project management](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1432).

Comment: That issue was closed, unfortunately. Let's vote at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15186 for the same.